# SKStoreReviewController not showing app icon in development

Tags: ios, storekit

I'm using `SKStoreReviewController` to show the built-in AppStore rating UI. When I test this locally, the app icon is not shown on the popup, instead Xcode's default icon (for projects without an icon) is shown. However, the app is configured correctly with an icon, which is displayed on the home screen.

Is this expected behavior or should the dialog contain the icon even in development mode? According to the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skstorereviewcontroller/2851536-requestreview), the dialog is not shown in TestFlight builds, so I cannot test this unless I release the feature, and I'd prefer not show this "broken" dialog to my users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone else stumbles across this problem: in the released version the icon was correctly shown. I think the issue was related to Xcode caching resources in dev mode somehow.