# Missing icon in Mac App Store review screen

Tags: xcode, mac-app-store, safari-app-extension

I have a Safari App Extension that uses `SKStoreReviewController` to request the Mac App Store rating screen:

[image: Screenshot]

The screen looks like it should have the app icon on the left side, but it doesn’t. I’ve tried setting `ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_APPICON_NAME` in Xcode to a valid asset name, but no change. Is this meant to work? If so, how do I get the icon there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if it's the same issue but looks like using `SKStoreReviewController` on iOS seems to trigger similar behaviour.  Does this issue also occur in the released version?

[SKStoreReviewController not showing app icon in development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51030769/skstorereviewcontroller-not-showing-app-icon-in-development)

Comment: Not released yet, will try as soon as possible. Thank you!

Comment: Fixed itself in the App Store version. ‍♂️

Comment: Thought it might! Glad you got it sorted 